# vertical margins inside a frame

Tags: beamer, spacing, margins

How can I change the vertical margins inside a frame. For example, how do I remove the space shown in the figure below:

[image]

Comment: Try with `\vspace{-1-5ex}`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fix the layout of a single slide which has special requirements than you can just follow @Fran 's advice and add a negative vertical space before the contents of the slide.

If instead your intention is to modify the theme, then you can use the beamer templating facilities: the template that typesets the title of the slide is called `frametitle`. You can change its appearance by doing `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{...}` (see manual for details) but instead here you may want to keep the template as it is and just add a negative space at the end:

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-2em}}
```

Then if you change theme this will still eat up some space between your frametitle and content.

`\addtobeamertemplate` takes the name of the template and the code to insert before and after it as the second and third argument respectively.